# Modify the logged header info in .NET Core

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a working .NET Core 2.2 application with [SeriLog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) . My web requests are logged too which is fine but for security reasons, I do not want to log the Authorization in the Header. Logically, [I can use](https://nblumhardt.com/2017/01/serilog-filtering-dsl/) `Filter.ByExcluding` . This works to just not log these kind of requests. In this method, I need to return true for confidential data. However, it would be better to replace/remove the header or part of it. In this way, only the confidential data is removed and the rest simply remains. So it would be nice to have a `Modify.BeRemoving` instead of `Filter.ByExcluding`. Is this possible? And how exactly?

Comment: best to fix the problem at source - this has been traversed once or twice in gitter.im/serilog in recent times - TL;DR you can write an enricher but you really shouldnt keep digging when in a hole

Comment: Are you familiar with a concrete example of such an "enricher"?

Comment: its very googleable - there are good docs about it. The aforementioned gitter has good info

Comment: Sure, but i am lookink for something that really works. What I find on google is not working.

Comment: step one is to share what you're trying. As the docs/intellisense will show when you go do some legwork, the APIs are clear. (Please don't make me do another loop of this)